# NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 2) error with mcar_test

Tags: r, nan, na, missing-data, infinite

I am new here so I hope I'm asking a question in an appropriate way.
I have a dataset ( `data_a` ) in which I am trying to do the MCAR- Test by the function  `mcar_test()`  in the package  `naniar`  in R. I found out that it doesn't work once I have replaced empty entries with NA. Before replacement, the function works.

I have tried to eliminate the rows containing only NA values. But the result is still the same. All the NA seem to be properly coded but the function still can't work with them.

Here is my cody:

```
library(naniar)
data_a <- read.csv("/Users/karo/Desktop/R/AG1/Daten/group_a.csv")
data_a <- data_a[,-c(2:7, 9, 145:153)]
mcar_test(data_a)#removing rows that only contain NA
data_a[data_a == "N/A" ] <- NA 
#the test still works
data_a[data_a == "" ] <- NA 
mcar_test(data_a)#the function doesn't work
data_a <- data_a[data_a$id != 1 & data_a$id != 21 & data_a$id != 31 &
                   data_a$id != 261 & data_a$id != 311 & 
                   data_a$id != 401, data_a$id != 501& data_a$id != 481  ,] 
mcar_test(data_a)#the function doesn't work
```

I always get  `Error in norm::em.norm(s, showits = FALSE) :  NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 2)`
. I used  `is.infinite()` and `is.nan()` to test whether part of the data is infinite or NaN, but none is.

My data set can be found here: https://osf.io/szg8h/

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTapB.png) are the first 10 rows of the data set once I have done all the NA- cleaning above.

I hope this was a fine description of the problem and this is a reproducible example.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: I suggest that you can set `na.strings` argument inside `read.csv()`, an example could be`read.csv("/Users/karo/Desktop/R/AG1/Daten/group_a.csv", na.strings=c("N/A"))`